# How to get td id val of table after change in php codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, codeigniter-3

The problem is whenever im drag & drop and replace td first place to another
i have receiving that the replacement id in jquery.
but the problem is how i can get that replacement td id value in php codeigniter.
i just need if any of td of table has been exchange then i should knw which one is is replaced and get that id into my controller class of php codeigniter.
thanks in advance.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

 $('tbody').addClass("DragMe");

 $('.DragMe').sortable({
  disabled: false,
  axis: 'y',
  items: "> tr:not(:first)",
  forceHelperSize: true,
  update: function (event, ui) {
   var Newpos = ui.item.index();
   var RefID = $('tr').find('td:first').html();


   //alert("Position " + Newpos + "..... RefID: " + RefID);
   $("#GridView1 tr:has(td)").each(function () {
    var RefID = $(this).find("td:eq(0)").html();
    var NewPosition = $("tr").index(this);
    alert(RefID + " " + NewPosition);
    $("#getpos").val(NewPosition);
    $("#ref").val(RefID);


   });

  }
 }).disableSelection();
});
```

```html
<style type="text/css">
   .DragMe:Hover {
   cursor: move;
   }
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<!-- here is my view form -->
<form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/dragcon/drag/dragfun">
   <table class="EU_DataTable" cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="GridView1" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <th scope="col">Ref ID</th>
            <th scope="col">Issue relates to</th>
         </tr>
         <tr class="ui-sortable-handle">
            <td id="ref">9392</td>
            <td id="getpos">CRM</td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="ui-sortable-handle">
            <td id="ref">9394</td>
            <td id="getpos">CRM</td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="ui-sortable-handle">
            <td id="ref">9308</td>
            <td id="getpos">eMail</td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="ui-sortable-handle">
            <td id="ref">9342</td>
            <td id="getpos">Other</td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="ui-sortable-handle">
            <td id="ref">9365</td>
            <td id="getpos">CRM</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" name="submit"></td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
</form>
```

As you seen where i can drag and drop td to td of table and also receiving in alert but i just want to get each of td value after change in the controller of  php codeigniter
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the difference between client side and server side code. The action you perform in Javascript can not be passed to the original Codeigniter script as that script was already executed.

In order to call back Codeigniter you want to use [Ajax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) and in particular the [Ajax functions of jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) since you seem to be using that.

It's a complex topic and you should study it in details to be sure you grasp the difference between server-side and client-side, when they happen and how they interact. If you want a more quick & dirty approach, [this article from IBM](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-aj-codeigniter/index.html) seems perfect as it talks about Ajax, jQuery and CodeIgniter.